# WSO2 can we use multiple instance of traffic manager with ELB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In clustered environment 
where we have ELB for multiple instances of publisher , store, gateway, keymanger
do we required ELB for traffic manager also ?

Comment: No clear information available in WSO2 documentation.  https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can cluster the traffic manager node. You can reffer following Doc for this, since there is no official guide yet. Traffic manager is a CEP instance running. You can refer High availability deployment section.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+CEP+4.1.0